# How to install a deb package with dependencies on something you have multiple versions of?

Tags: software-installation

I want to install a deb package that depends on python 3.4, which I have, however the installer thinks I only have 3.2 since that's `apt-cache` says, and `dpkg-query` returns `python3 3.2.3-0ubuntu1.2`. `update-alternatives` didn't seem to cut it. What can I do?

Comment: Could you please add the ouput of `dpkg-query -W python3` to your question and tag it with the release you're running (e.g 12.04 or 14.04)

Comment: When it comes to Python problems you must listen to @SylvainPineau

Comment: @SylvainPineau, python3 is python3.2, but I have separate packages for python3.3 and python3.4.

Comment: deb packages or did you install 3.4 from sources?

Comment: @SylvainPineau: All the python packages are from apt-get. The one that depends on them is a deb.

Comment: python 3.4 is not in the 12.04 Ubuntu archives (see http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python3). I you installed it via apt-get I guess that you set up a ppa to get it. And it probably did not install properly hence the 3.2 only known from your packaging/dependency system. Yo may find this [post](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-python-3-4-on-ubuntu-13-1012-1012-04-linux-mint-161413-and-elementary-os-0-2/) useful to install 3.4 on 12.04

Comment: @SylvainPineau: That's how I did it. Note that that ppa installs the package `python3.4`, not `python3`, which will remain pointing to 3.2. Does it behave otherwise on your system?

Comment: python3 and python3.4 are different packages, that explains your problem. What's the package you're trying to install? the one requiring python3 >= 3.4?

Comment: @SylvainPineau: Yes. Sorry I could not communicate my problem clearly enough to begin with. It's [python-tesseract](https://bitbucket.org/3togo/python-tesseract/downloads).

Comment: @SylvainPineau and Emre, can you please edit the important parts in the question/answer themself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a python3.4 package available in 12.04 won't be your only problem.

Look at the Debian control file:

```
Package: python3-tesseract
Source: python-tesseract
Version: 0.9-0.4ubuntu0
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: FreeToGo <FreeToGo@gmail.com>
Installed-Size: 4261
Depends: python3 (>= 3.4~), python3 (<< 3.5), libc6 (>= 2.14), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1), liblept4, libstdc++6 (>= 4.1.1), libtesseract3
Section: python
Priority: optional
Homepage: http://code.google.com/p/python-tesseract/
Description: Tesseract for Python3
 Python-tesseract is a wrapper class for Tesseract OCR
 that allows any conventional image files (JPG, GIF, PNG,
 TIFF and etc) to be read and decoded into readable
 languages. No temporary file will be created during the
 OCR processing.
```

`python3-tesseract` (and `python-tesseract`) depends on [liblept4](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/liblept4) which is only available in 14.04+.

My recommendation would be to set up a 14.04 VM or upgrade your system to 14.04 to properly install `python3-tesseract`.

Comment: Thanks, but I've already installed `liblept4`. I tried editing this control file and repackaging the deb file too, to no avail. I wanted to keep the question more general, though, to see if it was possible to deal with such problems. I guess you're saying no, or it's not worth the effort.

Comment: If you succeeded in installing (manually) the missing dep, then you could try to install the deb file using `dpkg --force-depends -i filename.deb`

Comment: If this last command worked could you please up vote the answer too? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, it failed with `py3compile: Requested versions are not installed`. I couldn't locate the second dependency check. Thank you for your time.